# I would like to access a local mysql database through my php script hosted on a remote server

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to access a local mysql database through my php script hosted on a remote server. Is there a way to code a script, that I save on the local mashine, and receives queries from my remote php script, executes, and the results are submitted back to the script?

How is this technology called?

I know, that I could just open the mysql port on my firewall, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: To send a request from remote server to local machine you **need** to open a port. If you don't want open mysql port, you can open http port and send http request to local php script. The local script interact with the db and send results to remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology is called [AJAX](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html).

Comment: and how will you access local database via PHP on remote server??

Comment: The PHP on the remote will use JS to send an AJAX request to a PHP script on the local server. The PHP script on the local server with perform the MySQL interactions and return the results via AJAX @FakhruddinUjjainwala Why do you ask?

Comment: How can AJAX send request to local machine from remote server. What will be the request URL? `localhost`? Something new for me!!

Comment: Since your local machine would be on the network it would have to have a network address @FakhruddinUjjainwala

Comment: The point is that I don't want to store the database user/psw in my app (running on the remote server), I would like to make a script, that I save on the local mashine and kinda tunnels the information for me.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes exactly. You mean to say `Static IP`, if I am not wrong here.

Comment: That is what you can do with AJAX @Joey. The user/pw info stays local to the database.

Comment: Right @FakhruddinUjjainwala, you have to give every device on your network an address.

Comment: Assume, that the IP problem is solved. So to sum up, what I can do:
1. A local php file has user/psw, and it can be reached via http
2. A remote php file makes a request to the local php file, the data is returned in json with ajax, and displayed?

Comment: @JayBlanchard but I guess this works if its an organization. Normally a home user will not have `Static IP Address`. I would suggest you mention regarding `Static IP` as well in your answer that will make it more clear to @Joey

Comment: His question was *"How is this technology called?"* @FakhruddinUjjainwala not, *"How do I do this?"* ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Thanks, for your help guys, since I'm a real noob, I didnt ask the question propely.

Comment: Yes @Joey, those are the basics. For instance, you could use [jQuery's AJAX functions](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) to realize what you're trying to do. You asked a pretty good question, it was very specific. Read the link I provided and search for some other AJAX tutorials. jQuery simplifies AJAX, so it is a good choice for getting into it as a newbie.

Comment: @JayBlanchard if you are suggesting him `Static IP` method why not access `MySQL` directly over static ip why is then a need for PHP script on local machine?

Comment: Because the OP doesn't want to expose his database like that @FakhruddinUjjainwala He wants a very specific setup where his database isn't exposed to remotes at all.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ok sir. Got it! :)